# How do I fix "attempt to index nil with 'character'" (Roblox)

Tags: lua, roblox

The output says: `Players.username.PlayerGui.replicated:18: attempt to index nil with 'Character'`

This is my code: `local Character = Player.Character or Player.CharacterAdded:Wait()`

How do I fix this?

Comment: What it means is you attempted to index a value (that is nil) with the string `Character` in the code you have presented you do this in 1 place `Player.Character` this mean `Player` is a nil value.

Answer (score 1):

"Attempt to index nil with ..." means that Player is nil, most likely because it hasn't been defined yet.

Make sure that Player has been defined, if it's being run in a LocalScript this can be done using `local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer`, or `script.Parent.Parent` since your script is running in PlayerGui.

If this doesn't work, providing a larger code snippet may help in getting a better answer.

Comment: I replaced the line of code with this and now it says  Players.username.PlayerGui.replicated:24: attempt to index nil with 'WaitForChild'. 

local Player = script:WaitForChild("player").Value
 local LocalPlayer = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
 local Player = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer
 local Humanoid = Character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
 local Camera = workspace:WaitForChild("Camera")
 local BowModel = script:WaitForChild("Shard Bow"):Clone()
 local Humanoid = Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Humanoid")

that is the larget piece of code

Answer (score 1):

The error message attempt to index nil with 'someOtherName' tells you that your doing one of the following operations:

```
someName.someOtherName
someName:SomeOtherName()
someName["SomeOtherName"]
```

where `someName` is a nil value. Indexing nil values is not allowed because it doesn't make sense. You may only index table values or values that have a __index metamethod.

So when you face that error go to the line that comes with the error message and look for any expression that does that index operation. Now you know the name of that nil value. Time to find out why it is nil.
Either you fix that, or if you cannot fix it because it happens outside of your code or is inteded to be nil, avoid indexing that nil value. For example using an if statement.